# Eclipse templates syntax

Tags: eclipse, templates

I've written a template to go with my use of JMock with this code in the Eclipse code template editor:

```
${imp:import(org.jmock.Expectations)}
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
}});
```

But when using it, it (maybe trying to be helpful) produces this:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {
    {

    }
});
```

How can I get around this and fix the location of the curly braces?

Comment: I dont't get the extra curly braces line.

Comment: Doh, sorry, when I re-pasted a slightly amended version earlier, I used the template as I'm using it now (it's easier to add the extra {} than to fix the annoyingly placed ones!). Notice now there's {{ }} in the template. Sorry!